# How to use <p:watermark> for <p:inplace> editor

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, watermark, in-place-editor

I want to use `<p:watermark>` for a `<p:inplace>` editor. I tried it as below

```
<p:watermark for="txtSvcName" value="Please enter service name..." />
<p:inplace id="ipSvcName" editor="true" >                                   
    <p:inputText id="txtSvcName" value="#{service.serviceName}"  maxlength="50" 
     readonly="#{not subMerchantManagement.editPerspective}"    converter="UpperCaseConverter" />                                   
</p:inplace>
```

but unfortunately that doesn't work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please do not use `[jsf-1.2]` tag if you aren't asking a question about JSF 1.2.

Comment: I am sorry, u are right; i guess, i used wrong tag. I will try to be more carefull about that. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/watermark.jsf), you have to call `p:watermark` via javascript when some event is happened. You have lots of events over `p:inputText` where you can make your call: `onblur`, `onchange`... Just call `PrimeFaces.showWatermarks();` function when the one you need happens. You should take a look to [Primefaces Documentation](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html) too, because there is another function to clean the Watermarks when you need it. Good luck.

**EDITED**

You can trigger an ajax event when user saves inplaced content. When that request is processed just call the show function and update the main container. I guess it will be useful.

```
<p:panel id="panel">
    <p:watermark for="txtSvcName" value="Please enter service name..." />
    <p:inplace id="ipSvcName" editor="true" emptyLabel="Please enter service name..." >                                   
        <p:inputText id="txtSvcName" value="#{service.serviceName}" maxlength="50" 
            readonly="#{not subMerchantManagement.editPerspective}"    converter="UpperCaseConverter" /> 
        <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{subMerchantManagement.handleSave}" 
            oncomplete="PrimeFaces.showWatermarks();" update="panel" />  
    </p:inplace>
</p:panel>
```

Comment: Thank u for your response. I analyzed the PF Guide. But actually i couldnt find a solution about this situation; where should i use that show and clear functions? Have u got any idea?

Comment: You're welcome. It depends on what you want to achieve. I have edited my response with some functionality that can be useful.

Comment: Thank you again. Actually, the watermark doesnt show the text initially when the textbox is in inplace editor. I guess we can also use a javascript for a workaround for this issue. I am thinking that I will give an initial value to the textbox and i will clear the textbox value while onclick event is fired.

Comment: You can call `Primefaces.showWatermarks()` when the page is loaded or call it when the `p:inputText` is clicked using `onclick="PrimeFaces.showWatermarks();"`

Comment: Hey, I found the problem. Inplace doesnt show the inner element if its value is empty. When i use 'emptyLabel' attribute for innerplace, everything works fine. Thank u for your all answers...

Comment: You're welcome man. You can edit my answer or create your own one in order to mark the question as answered.